# How did I create this double path (Illustrator)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was creating a graphic last night with a collection of paths, and later on realized that they had all somehow converted into double strokes.[image]

I like the effect, but it's making live painting a complete pain since the space between each path needs it's own fill area. It would be nice to know how to turn this on and off, and replicate at a later time.

The posts I have found online seem to suggest that the methods for double strokes are a bit hacky, but I definitely didn't do anything on purpose to turn this on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expanded your strokes into fills:

[image: the "Expand" dialog]

Somehow you must have missed this dialog, which asked for confirmation. It is not an "applied effect"; you cannot turn it on and off. That means you're stuck with what you have now.

See [the online Help](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/grouping-expanding-objects.html#expand_objects) for more on "Expand".

Comment: By golly you're right! Thank you, that was driving me nuts. I guess missing dialogs is a good way to find out about new techniques.

Comment: @Mrweiner: in case you're interested: I believe there are a few ways to do this as a *proper* effect, so you can experiment with widths and styles (and also turn it off ). Maybe someone knows how to right off the bat and can add an answer here - if not, feel free to post it as a separate question.

Comment: I would be interested in that if anybody cares to chime in. I did find a couple of tutorials in my search, so I'm sure one of those would work. Wouldn't hurt to have something in here for anybody who runs across it in the future, though.